# Is it safe to import a view controller to another controller for segueing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, viewcontroller

I am currently going through the iTunes U Stanford iOS dev. course and I am trying to utilize segues.

In my prepareForSegue method I am trying to update the data on the transitioning VC and this is my code:

```
    -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
     {
        if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"changeToScreen2"])
         {
             if([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[Screen2ViewController class]])
                {
                    "Code to be implemented"
                }
         }
     }
```

But my Screen2ViewController isn't recognized. Is it safe and proper coding technique to import a view controller to another view controller for segueing purposes or is there another method I should implement?

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**I have a new problem now**

When I set the values of a UILabel and UITextView with the aforementioned prepareForSegue method and change to Screen2ViewController the labels and text views have not be updated with the values that I have added.

```
    Screen2ViewController *S2VC = (Screen2ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    S2VC.myLabel.text = @"Screen 2 is now being viewed";
        S2VC.uneditableText.text = @"Why aren't you showing up when I push you";
```

But these values don't get updated.

Comment: If you're talking about importing the header-file, then yes, it is not only safe,  but the way you're supposed to do it...

Comment: Yes it's safe and it's the way you're supposed to do it. I think at some point in the iTunes U course it is shown as well.

Comment: Please don't add a second question. If you have another inner, add it as another one! Otherwise, we would need to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is safe to import view controllers. There are a few caveats however,

Do not import 2 headers into each other, this will cause non-obvious error.

```
Screen1ViewController.h
#import "Screen2ViewController.h"

Screen2ViewController.h
#import "Screen1ViewController.h"
```

Import in the .m file instead

```
Screen1ViewController.h
#import "Screen2ViewController.h"

Screen2ViewController.h
//No imports
Screen2ViewController.m

#import "Screen1ViewController.h"
```

As a general rule I try to put all the imports in the .m file: both for encapsulation and the above reason. You can also foreword declare a class if you need to use both classes in both header files.

Answer (score 0):

About your new problem: you can only update instances from another view controller if they're made public (in other words, they're declared in its header file). So, with the provided code, you'd need to make `myLabel` and `uneditableText` public. However, during `prepareForSegue:` execution they were not yet allocated. As all you need from those objects is editing their `text`, it would be better to define two `NSString`'s in the second view controller and then, inside that VC's implementation, you assign them to the objects. Example:

### First View Controller

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
     {
        if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"changeToScreen2"])
         {
             if([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[Screen2ViewController class]])
                {
                    Screen2ViewController *S2VC = (Screen2ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
                    S2VC.labelText = @"Screen 2 is now being viewed";
                    S2VC.textViewText = @"Why aren't you showing up when I push you";
                }
         }
     }
```

### Second View Controller's Header

```
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *labelText;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *textViewText;
...
```

### Second View Controller's Implementation File

```
...
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.myLabel.text = self.labelText;
     self.uneditableText.text = self.textViewText;
}
...
```

Needless to say you must have previously used the Interface Builder to add `myLabel` and `uneditableText` as `@property`'s of your Second View Controller.